# Azure search sorting like localeCompare javascript functionality

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am getting a record from azure search in ascending order 1.0,10.1,2, 2.1,3.1.1 But my business requirement is they want sorting like that 1.0,2,2.1,3.1.1,10.1

for more details please find attachments. 
[azure search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8mSt.png)

Comment: You could use `$orderby=[string]` to achieve it. The default is ascending order. For more, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#orderbystring-optional).

Comment: @JoeyCai thanks for reply...
Currently my azure search query, make like that and so in that query how can I add my condition


&search=*&$orderby=versionLower desc&$count=true&$top=100&$skip=0

Please suggest me......

Comment: You could use `filter` in [azure search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-filters#filter-design-patterns).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$orderby=[string] asc` to get record in ascending order.

Also, you could use `$filter` to add condition. Such as below:

```
&search=*&$count=true&$orderby=versionLower desc&$filter=top eq 100 and skip eq 0
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-filters).